# Unable to select a range of cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to here so I'm not sure the rules that well. I currently stumbling at a code that I can't seem to know the problem.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Format(Range("H4").Value, "HH:MM:SS") = "00:15:00" Then
        MsgBox "Block 3 ends in 15 mins"             
    End If
End Sub
```

The code is able to handle a single cell but when I change the cell "H4" to "H2:H7" it will not work.
Please help and thank you for the advance.

Comment: Of course there is not one `.Value` for multiple cells `H2:H7` but multiple values. Therefore you will need to test each value on its own in a loop. And you need to decide if **all** of the cells need to meet the `If` criteria or only one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there is not one `.Value` for multiple cells `H2:H7` but multiple values.

Therefore you will need to test each value on its own in a loop. And you need to decide if all of the cells need to meet the If criteria or only one of them.

This is an Example for a massage box whenever a value in the range `H2:H7` is `00:15:00`.
Note that this runs on every change of **any** cell.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("H2:H7")
        If Format$(c.Value, "HH:MM:SS") = "00:15:00" Then
            MsgBox "Block 3 ends in 15 mins"
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

If you want that only to run when a cell in `Range("H2:H7")` is changed use

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H2:H7")) Is Nothing Then
        Dim c As Range
        For Each c In Range("H2:H7")
            If Format$(c.Value, "HH:MM:SS") = "00:15:00" Then
                MsgBox "Block 3 ends in 15 mins"
            End If
        Next c
    End If
End Sub
```

If you want to test only the changed cell (not the whole range) use

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H2:H7")) Is Nothing Then
        If Format$(Target.Value, "HH:MM:SS") = "00:15:00" Then
            MsgBox "Block 3 ends in 15 mins"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```